# How to convert a UTC date time to Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5)

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

How can I convert a UTC date/time to Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5)? I'm mostly worried about Daylight Savings, so I can not simply do `MyUTCDateTime - 5 hours` (I think).

Comment: Look at [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-systemtimetotzspecificlocaltime): "*Converts a time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to a specified time zone's corresponding local time.*"

Comment: It depends on whether you're concerned with the fact that the DST change date has not always been the same. If you use the function above listed by Remy, it'll take care of DST changes, _as per the current change dates_, ie. it doesn't (as far as I know) have a database that tells which dates the change occured for all years back in time. To do this properly, you'll need to download the TZ database (others can probably tell you where) and the appropriate Delphi wrapper to it.